# General formula for loci of a circle in the Complex Plane

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, locus

So, I basically want to show that points $z$ satisfying
$|z - a| = k|z - b|$ (where $a$ and $b$ are also complex)
gives me a circle of radius $$\frac{k|a - b|}{|1-k^2|},$$ centred at $$\frac{a-bk^2}{1-k^2}.$$

I tried to boil this down to a cartesian equation that showed me the properties of the circle I was looking for, found the centre by doing this, but still (as you can imagine) ended up in a horrible algebraic mess, with no hope of showing my right hand side was in fact the square of the radius.

Is there a "neater" way of deriving that we have a circle with the above centre and radius?

Many thanks!
Sam

Comment: Use $\LaTeX\text{}$

Answer (score 0):

Presumably $k > 0$.  To reduce the algebraic mess, take advantage of symmetry.
You want the centre to be at $a - k^2 b$, so let's translate so  that is $0$.
Then rotate and scale so that $b=1$ and  $a = k^2$.  Now your equation is
$|z - k^2| = k |z - 1|$.  Squaring both sides,
$$ (z - k^2)(\overline{z} - k^2) = k^2 (z - 1)(\overline{z} - 1)$$
 Now expand and simplify.

Comment: Thanks. So I get this down to a circle, centre 0 and radius k|1-k^2|/|1-k^2| which is good. But how do I do the scaling and rotation to get to this point?

Comment: Divide by $b$.  That is, $|z - a| = k |z - b|$ iff $|w - a/b| = k |w - 1|$, where $w = z/b$.  Note that this mapping preserves circles.